# E: Unable to locate package mysql-pwd

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Estoy intentando desinstalar mysql de mi ubuntu 18.04 desktop. Si ejecuto

```
~$ sudo apt-get remove -y mysql-*
```

obtengo:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-pwd
```

Comment: Hola, Alejandro. ¿Has podido solucionar? ¿Alguna de las respuestas te sirvió de ayuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No parece el método apropiado para desinstalar mysql. Para desinstalar mysql correctamente de tu sistema debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common -y
$ sudo apt-get autoremove -y
$ sudo apt-get autoclean
$ rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

Alejandro:

MYSQL_PWD es una variale de entorno que usa MySQL por lo que no hay un packete llamado mysql-pwd Podrías consultar más en el siguiente enlace: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/environment-variables.html

Podrías consultar todos los paquetes disponibles con el comando apt-cache search:

```
$ -> apt-cache search mysql | grep -i '^mysql*'
```

Y luego filtrar para verificar que exista en el repositorio alguno con el string 'pwd'

```
$ -> apt-cache search mysql | grep -i '^mysql*' | grep -i pwd
```

En mi caso no existe.

Luego con el comando apt list puedes buscar los paquetes instalados en el sistema:

```
$ -> apt list --installed | grep -i mysql
mysql-client-core-5.7/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 5.7.30-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [instalado]
mysql-common/bionic,bionic,now 5.8+1.0.4 all [instalado, automático]
```

Luego, si quieres eliminar algún paquete de mysql, podrías utilizar el comando apt-get remove|purge

```
apt-get remove mysql-package
```

O:

```
apt-get purge mysql-package
```

Donde package es tu paquete.

Ten en cuenta qué:

- remove: elimina los paquetes pero deja ficheros de configuración.
- purge: Hace lo mismo que remove pero con ficheros de configuración incluídos.

Espero haber sido de ayuda.